# Retrieve all Managed Devices using Java (with Microsoft Graph API SDK)

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, azure-java-sdk

I would like to retrieve all devices managed by Intune (managed devices) using the Microsoft Graph Java SDK. I have created the app in Microsoft Azure and given the appropriate API permissions:

[API Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i17BO.png)

The following code creates a graphClient object and a method that retrieves all managed devices.

```
    @Service
public class AzureServiceDefault implements AzureService
    {
        private static final String CLIENT_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"});
        private static final String TENANT = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
        ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(CLIENT_ID, SCOPES, CLIENT_SECRET, TENANT, NationalCloud.Global);
        IGraphServiceClient graphClient;
    
        public AzureServiceDefault()
        {
            graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient();
    
        } 

    @Override
        public List<IntuneDevice> getManagedDevices()
        {
            IManagedDeviceCollectionRequestBuilder managedDeviceRequestBuilder;
            IDeviceManagementRequestBuilder builder = graphClient.deviceManagement();
            IDeviceManagementRequest managedDevicesRequest = builder.buildRequest();
            List<ManagedDevice> managedDevices = new ArrayList<>();
            List<IntuneDevice> allManagedDevices = new ArrayList<>();
            
            do {
                try {
                    DeviceManagement deviceManagement = managedDevicesRequest.get();
                    ManagedDeviceCollectionPage managedDevicesCollectionPage = deviceManagement.managedDevices;
                    
                    //Process items in the response
                    managedDevices.addAll(managedDevicesCollectionPage.getCurrentPage());
                    managedDevices.stream().forEach((device) -> allManagedDevices.add(new IntuneDevice(device.id, 
                                                                                               device.userId,
                                                                                               device.deviceName,
                                                                                               device.managedDeviceOwnerType.toString(),
                                                                                               device.operatingSystem,
                                                                                               device.osVersion,
                                                                                               device.complianceState.toString(),
                                                                                               device.azureADRegistered,
                                                                                               device.azureADDeviceId,
                                                                                               device.userPrincipalName,
                                                                                               device.model,
                                                                                               device.manufacturer,
                                                                                               device.serialNumber)));
                
                
                
                    //Build the request for the next page, if there is one
                    managedDeviceRequestBuilder = managedDevicesCollectionPage.getNextPage();
                    if (managedDeviceRequestBuilder == null)
                    {
                        managedDevicesRequest = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        managedDevicesRequest = (IDeviceManagementRequest) managedDeviceRequestBuilder.buildRequest();
                    }
                }
                catch(ClientException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    managedDevicesRequest = null;
                }
    
            } while (managedDevicesRequest != null);
            
            return allManagedDevices;
 

           }
    }
```

The problem is that the variable managedDevices turns out to be null and this is the error message:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.ManagedDeviceCollectionPage.getCurrentPage()" because "managedDevicesCollectionPage" is null] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.microsoft.graph.requests.extensions.ManagedDeviceCollectionPage.getCurrentPage()" because "managedDevicesCollectionPage" is null
```

What do I need to change to make this code work? I am succesfully able to retrieve all users in Azure AD, but I am having difficulties getting data from Intune/Endpoint Manager. Do I need to make changes to the SCOPES?

It should be possible to retrieve all managed devices as the REST API for it is https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceManagement/managedDevices

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-manageddevice-list?view=graph-rest-1.0) does not support application permissions, so you couldn't list managedDevices with `ClientCredentialProvider`. ClientCredentialProvider is based on client credential flow that requires application permission.

[image]

You could use [AuthorizationCodeProvider](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java-auth#a-authorization-code-provider) to get the list. And follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) to get AUTHORIZATION_CODE first.

```
    String CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxx";
    List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(new String[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" });
    String CLIENT_SECRET = "xxxxxx";
    String TENANT = "xxxxxx";
    String AUTHORIZATION_CODE = "";
    String REDIRECT_URL = "xxxxxx";

    AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(CLIENT_ID, SCOPES, AUTHORIZATION_CODE,
            REDIRECT_URL, NationalCloud.Global, TENANT, CLIENT_SECRET);

    IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient();

    IManagedDeviceCollectionPage managedDeviceCollectionPage = graphClient.deviceManagement().managedDevices().buildRequest().get();
    List<ManagedDevice> managedDeviceList = managedDeviceCollectionPage.getCurrentPage();
```

Comment: Hi, @mscola1975. If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your help @pamela-peng.Your answer was helpful and sorry for the late reply.